# Correct citation of “The method of successive approximation for functional equations” by L. Kantorovich, Leningrad, 1939?

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis

The citation we get from http://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-71/issue-none/The-method-of-successive-approximation-for-functional-equations/10.1007/BF02547750.full says `number={none}` in the BIB file and no `IS` entry in the RIS file and no visible month and the date `PY  - 1939/1/1` in the RIS file.

The citation we get from http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02547750#citeas says, on the contrary, `IS = 1` (and mentions an `SN` entry, though ISSN/ISBN were introduced much later) in the RIS file and month `December` visibly and the date `DA  - 1939/12/01` in the RIS file.

- What's the reason behind this discrepancy?
- Which data is right? Why?
- Does this publication have any issue number at all? If so, which one?
- What's the true month of the publication?

Comment: I think when the article was published there were no issue numbers, but now there are.  A correct citation in an article would give just author's name, article title, journal title, volume number, page number, year.

Comment: If you look at the last line of printing on pages whose page numbers are congruent to 1 modulo 16, you will see that this paper was printed on 2 March, 3 March, and 15 March of 1939.  The first article in volume 72 was printed on 29 November 1939.  These dates represent completion of intermediate steps in the production of the volume: publication would come only after the signatures were bound.  I would guess the bound volume 71 was published in December 1939 or maybe a bit later.

Comment: I've found that many publishers (Springer in math, especially) have basically "dropped the ball" regarding issue/month designations for journal volumes before roughly the mid to late 1950s, and simply assign the entire volume as "issue 1, December 19xx". In many cases that I have investigated (by visiting several libraries in search of those in which the issue covers are included in the bound volumes), there ARE various issues and there ARE month (or season, or double-month, etc.) dates for the issues (and in some cases with clear separate issues, they are only dated with the year).